# How should I format/repair a write-protected laptop SSD with I/O errors?

Tags: windows-10

The NVMe hard drive in my Lenovo Thinkpad is write-protected and I cannot get anything to work. I cannot even boot into Windows.

I have tried many options including:

- Windows Recovery USB: all options fail
- Reinstalling Windows: fails
- [GParted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) (deleting partitions): fails due to I/O errors
- Starting in safe mode with a command prompt and running format,
  diskpart, and chkdsk: "The disk is write protected"
- Changing registry key
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies to 0
- Wipe using DD from Parted Magic: "Device I/O error" and hundreds of similar
  errors

How do I recover my SSD and get my laptop booting again?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and informative comments. I replaced the SSD in my laptop and am getting Windows installed now.

Comment: Make sure you install the update KB4571744 if you install Windows 10 2004

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don’t. Once the drive is dead, it’s dead.

The drive is bad. Write protected mode is a safety feature to hopefully allow you to recover the data that is still there.

It’s time to recover what data you can and replace it.

Comment: At the end of their life SSDs enter into a read-only mode, where they allow you to copy everything. I read somewhere that, after a reboot, some SSDs in read-only mode won't show up ever again. I can't find where I read it, but, it was an old article. But something to always keep in mind. If it is read-only and detected, **BACKUP AT THAT MOMENT**.

Comment: I'm having a hard time accepting that the ssd is dead. The laptop is less than 2 years old... Shouldn't the ssd last much longer?

Comment: @creeve4 on average, they do, but individual drives may fail earlier. It also depends a lot on technology, write cycles, write amplification, ...

Comment: Maybe getting starting to get off-topic for this thread, but how does one wipe an SSD that entered its write-protect mode, for secure disposal? Is the only option physically breaking the flash chips at that point?

Comment: @nanofarad I do think that is somewhat opinion based. It’s possible the manufacturer has a secure erase mechanism that would still function. But in this case, I would say shredding the drive would be best.

Comment: @creeve4 google "bathtub curve"; there's always a few devices that pass manufacturer QA, work for a little while, and then fail.

Comment: @creeve4 *The laptop is less than 2 years old* → just as a side note, if you are in Europe you are very likely covered by a legal warranty

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've read this article a while ago, and it mentions about Intel SSDs bricking themselves after a reboot: https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead/

Comment: @PNDA YES!!! That's the article! It states that the Intel 335 went into read-only and after a reboot, it was bricked. Thank you! This is important info that I think that *should* be added to the answer.

Comment: @nanofarad It depends. If the SSD can't be read, nothing. If the SSD can be read but is in read-only and still works after reboots, then you can try a secure erase command. The secure erase command doesn't touch the user data, just changes the encryption key. As long as the controller storage is fine, then it should delete everything just fine.

Comment: @pjc50 I had that happen to me once. A brand new SSD died in just 3 hours, after installing Windows and all the software. It was just the final minutes before the laptop was completely done. ... And the controller died on it ...

Comment: @creeve4 The SSD isn't dead.... Yet...... Backup **RIGHT NOW**, or you may end with a bricked drive and no data. Also, report it to Lenovo. It may be that the flash was being overheated and caused an accelerated death. If this is the case, try to see if others with similar models had that problem too. If they did, try and check if there's a warranty program or recall that you can take advantage of. But, again, **BACKUP NOW**.

Comment: @creeve4 Also, something that MAY have killed the SSD: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-fixes-windows-10-bug-causing-excessive-ssd-defragging/ Aparently, the update KB4571744 fixes an issue where SSDs were being optimized too often, and plenty of articles say that this kills SSDs. This may have been the cause. This update is optional, so, this MAY be the reason why the SSD died in 2 year (heat is another reason for that), and others may not have this update installed and, if true, their SSDs could be at risk as well. But take this with a pinch of salt.

Comment: One thing nobody mentioned is that SSDs actually read the data destructively, so internally they need to re-write the data again. The read-only lock therefore does not prevent further writes and degradation of the SSD, so backing up the data NOW is of utmost importance.

Comment: @JohnEye I’ve never heard of such a thing and it sounds counter-intuitive. Can you provide a reference for your comment?

Comment: @JohnEye: I would have thought that most SSD drives would use some form of flash, rather than other other technologies such as ferroelectric memory that would use destructive reads.  Although the write speeds for individual flash chips are rather poor, sustained write speeds can easily be scaled up by subdividing the storage into distinct flash chips.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Flash drives will periodically copy information from one location to another and erase the old location, and there are some other memory technologies where all reads are destructive; perhaps some kinds of SSD which are intended for write-heavy purposes use destructive-read memory technologies, but I'm unaware of any that do so for bulk data storage.  I can imagine that some drives might use destructive-read technologies to hold book-keeping data (since they allow bytes to be written individually, and rewritten many orders of magnitude more times than flash, one could...

Comment: ...permanently allocate a few bytes on such devices to store the present location of each page of data in the bulk flash array, rather than having to use data structures with multiple layers of indirection for the purpose) but I don't know the details of how any particular drive does things.

Comment: @supercat It seems I was mistaken about the principles of Flash memory, apologies for confusing the readers. Will keep the original message so your reply makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Flash chips are limited to writing information onto blank pages.  Although flash drives can erase and reuse areas of storage, this is a relatively slow process, and is limited to erasing fairly large blocks of memory (typically e.g. 512 pages of 528 bytes) at a time.  While it would be theoretically possible to design a flash drive that would respond to a write requests by erasing the old data and then immediately reusing the same storage, no practical drives do that.  Instead, they will write the new data to a new location, and record somewhere the facts that the data should be read from a new location, and that the copy in the old location is no longer needed.  When the drive is idle, it will find the blocks that have the largest number of obsolete pages on them and erase them in preparation for reuse.

All of this can work very well and very efficiently provided that the mechanisms the drive uses for storing book-keeping information remain reliable.  If the bookkeeping information becomes corrupted, however, the drive may erroneously reuse blocks that hold live data.  This would obviously be bad if the drives hold user data, but can be downright disastrous if the blocks hold bookkeeping data.

Although quality drives should maintain bookkeeping data with enough cross-checks to minimize the likelihood of data loss in case part of it gets corrupted, there are limits to the amount of cross-checking that drives can do while maintaining a reasonable level of performance.  Consequently, if corruption is detected, many drives will enter a "safe mode" to avoid any possibility of further corruption.

A nasty quirk of flash memory, btw, is that if a block of memory has been erased a certain number of times, it may get into a state where reading it immediately after writing will correctly yield the data written, but bits may spontaneously change later after month or so.  When everything is working correctly, drives will keep track of how many times each block has been erased and will cease trying to use a block once it has been erased too many times.  If a drive's bookkeeping information gets corrupted, however, it will have no way of knowing how many times blocks have been erased, and thus have no way of knowing which blocks are safe to use.  Worse, it will have no way of knowing whether any particular block that it has just written will be reliable for any meaningful length of time.

If one has data recovery tools that know how the bookkeeping information for a particular drive is stored, they may be possible to do a much better job of recovering drive contents than would be possible using normal methods of reading and writing.  If a drive has both a "current" and "obsolete" copies of a a few blocks of bookkeeping information, for example, and some of the information that was corrupted on the current copies is correct on the "obsolete" ones, a data recovery tool may be able to use different combinations of old and new data to see if any of them "make sense" when looking at the drives' contents as a whole.  A drive would not have enough RAM and CPU horsepower to accomplish such things, but specialized data recovery tools could.  Because different drives use different bookkeeping approaches, however, I would expect the necessary tools to be highly specialized and for many types of drive might only exist on if a data-recovery specialist has needed to create one.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can get into the recovery environment type:

Diskpart-hit enter
nexttype:
Clean-hit enter

Then format the drive for ntfs
when that completes, type Diskpart - hit enter
& then type: Clean- hit enter

exit out & try to reinstall your OS.

I hope you first saved everything you wanted to keep before you started any of this. Good Luck. If this doesn't work get another drive to replace this one. Then try salvaging anything from the first before you rip out the super magnets in the crashed drive.