# Deleting SSD partitions fail, after initializing restores old partition table

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ssd, format

I have an SSD that worked with Windows 10, but after an update, it did not open again. I tried to restore the system but it failed, I tried to format it as an external disk but always failed, I have tried a lot of applications like easus, paragon etc and many OS (OSX, Linux) but nothing happened, the problem is that after initialization the SSD keeps the same partition...

---

This is the SSD status before formatting:
[image: Screenshot showing the SSD format]

Then, I use CMD to clean the partitions:
[image: Screenshot of CMD cleaning the partitions]

Now, the SSD is shown as an unallocated disk and needs to initialize:
[image: Screenshot showing the need to initialize]

But it always returns a disk with 2 partitions:
[image: Screenshot showing the disk now has two partitions]

It does not let me set it up as a new single volume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entire drive (SATA SSD) is write protected, how to remove the protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585629/entire-drive-sata-ssd-is-write-protected-how-to-remove-the-protection)

Comment: Use another partition manager.  You can find many for free on the web.