# Formating a drive that is locked by Windows Bitlocker

Tags: ssd, bitlocker, format

A friend asked me if I could save her laptop. A year ago her Microsoft Surface Laptop 2 has locked her out and nobody so far was able to bring it back to life. A very interesting and annoying fact about this laptop is that It's almost impossible to open it up and replace the ssd hard drive with a new one without breaking anything.
Anyways, she gave me the recovery key, using the command prompt I can unlock the volume 0 (C:) and see all the information but when I want to turn off the Bitlocker security it says that the drive is write protected. At this point I only want to format it and reinstall windows 10 but none of the tools I have been using are able the break the "read only" attibrutes.
If anybody has a different idea or way to do this I would really appreciate to hear it!
Thanks in advance!

Diego

Comment: Are you sure it's caused by BitLocker? There is no "write protection" feature in it...

Comment: When an SSD is approaching end of life it will often go into read-only mode to protect the data on it. This allows you, the user, to recover the data, but it will prevent further disk writes  in order to do this. It is highly likely this is what is going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I format/repair a write-protected laptop SSD with I/O errors?](https://superuser.com/questions/1583989/how-should-i-format-repair-a-write-protected-laptop-ssd-with-i-o-errors)

Comment: Honestly I do not know if it is Bitlocker who is causing the ssd to be write protected. How can I tell if it is something else?

Comment: @DiegoToccaceli - You would have to give us some more specifics about the exact message, in your question you claim it's BitLocker giving you this message, except locking your drive isn't a feature of BitLocker.

Comment: @Ramhound - I will try to clarify the situation. Without loading windows, I get to the command prompt, then enter manage-bde -unlock C: -rp (+Recovery Key) and I get the message that The password successfully unlocked volume C:, then I try to enter manage-bde -off C: and the message I get is ERROR: An error occurred (0x80070013): The media is write protected. As far as I understand, I am able to unlock the drive but because it is still write protected I can't do much more. Is it because of Bitlocker or is there something else that is keeping the drive write protected?

Comment: @DiegoToccaceli It is the drive itself which has gone into read-only mode. You need to copy the data from it before it fails completely and becomes unreadable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Thank you Andrew, at this point my friend is not longer interested in the data, she just want her laptop back. I have been watching some YouTube videos about this particular laptop and they say the level of reparability of this laptop is zero. The ssd is not removable (Next thing i was going to try, replacing it), so basically once any of the main components go bad you have to basically replace the entire laptop. So my goal would be formating the ssd somehow, so far nothing worked.

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. available? What does it say?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hannu, I would love to give you an answer but I don't know what you mean by S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.  - I have no idea which Windows feature or software to use, on a Linux machine you open a Shell/CLI/Command prompt and type e.g, `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` (+enter) for the status readout (text) of the first HDD

Answer (score -1):

What are you using to start the machine and mount c:?
If you are using a usb based boot disk, possibly, that boot medium has mounted the volume c: as read-only, that happens.

You can use the command prompt tool diskpart to fix that: https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-to-read-write-and-format.html#part1
(make sure that the disk that holds c: is indeed number 0 by using the command diskpart and afterwards the command list disk)